# statute of limitations on injuries in the workplace in israel?

Tags: employment, workplace, injury, israel

A year ago I got hit by a metal bar on my leg. I didn't tell anyone because I have a **speech problem** and heavy **shyness**. It hurt me the first day and later the doctor told me it was not broken and gave me medicine. The pain stopped for a while but has returned now and again even after a year.

So is there anything I do? Sadly I don't have a witness or anything

Answer (score 3):

### Statute of limitations is the least of your problems

To answer your headline question is 7 years.

However, the problem that you have is I hear (and your employer and the court will hear): "I **say** I suffered this injury at work but I didn't report it, no one saw it happen, I didn't tell anyone at the time and I didn't see a doctor until 'later'." What are you going to say when they ask you for *evidence* of your claim?

Comment: does an age estimation of an injury and a lie-detecting test consider proof in this case?

Comment: First, I’m not even sure you can medically age an injury. Second, knowing how old it is doesn’t mean it happened at work. Third, lie detectors are not admissible evidence for the same reason that horoscopes and tarot cards aren’t - they’re bullshit.